# Handling OutOfBoundsDatetime error in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply few functions on a pandas data frame, but am getting OutOfBoundsDatetime error -

```
def data_cleanser(data):
        clean_df = data.str.strip().str.replace(r'\\', '')
        return clean_df

connection = pyodbc.connect(conn)
sql = 'SELECT * FROM {}'.format(tablename) 
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
df.replace([None], np.nan, inplace=True)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df=df.applymap(str)
df = df.apply(lambda x: data_cleanser(x))
```

Error message:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Python_Scripts/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 763, in replace
    copy=not inplace) for b in blocks]
  File "/Python_Scripts/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 763, in <listcomp>
    copy=not inplace) for b in blocks]
  File "/Python_Scripts/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2135, in convert
    blocks = self.split_and_operate(None, f, False)
  File "/Python_Scripts/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 478, in split_and_operate
    nv = f(m, v, i)
  File "/Python_Scripts/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2125, in f
    values = fn(v.ravel(), **fn_kwargs)
  File "/Python_Scripts/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 807, in soft_convert_objects
    values = lib.maybe_convert_objects(values, convert_datetime=datetime)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1290, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1575, in pandas._libs.tslib.convert_to_tsobject
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1669, in pandas._libs.tslib.convert_datetime_to_tsobject
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1848, in pandas._libs.tslib._check_dts_bounds
pandas._libs.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 07:00:00
```

Sample data frame:

| appointment_id | start_time | end_time | emp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 302205 | 2016-10-26 17:30:00 | 2016-10-26 18:30:00 | 45807 |
| 462501 | 2017-04-10 13:00:00 | NaT | 45807 |

How can i avoid this error?

Comment: Seems like one of your Dates is ending up as the year 1 AD. Which is of course out of bounds for `pandas` timestamps. It would help if we could have a sample of your DataFrame/Database input to see why/where this is happening.

Comment: Added sample data frame in original question now

Comment: Would it be because of NaT values?

Comment: that sample data does not trigger the error. Somewhere in your data, there is a `1-01-01 07:00:00` timestamp. Maybe trying to read sql without parsing the dates...

Comment: You don't have any shown code that parses Datetime (explicitly). My best guess would be that there is an incompatibility between some value in the database vs how it's being imported into pandas. Or specifically the content of your Database has an incompatible value. Either way it seems the issue is in the database not pandas.

Comment: The start_time dtype shows datetime64[ns]